# Importing CSV file to MySql database gives error

Tags: mysql, csv

I am developing an application in which I want to import a csv file into database table. while importing I get error and I am not able to import the file. can anyone help me on this.I am using MySql workbench 5.6.13 . Below is my error.

```
18:11:18 Restoring E:\text.csv

Running: mysql.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\users\crevavi\appdata\local\temp\tmpvivnpy.cnf"  --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=demo < "E:\\text.csv"

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '123,16/02/25,19:02:40,My,hello,thankyou,welcome,visit again,haha,good morning,sw' at line 1


Operation failed with exitcode 1

18:11:18 Import of E:\text.csv has finished with 1 errors
```

Comment: Can you share a record of csv file?

Comment: this is one row of csv table.

Comment: As explained in my answer, we need to enclose the fields into quotes. Have a look at the link.

Comment: I tried with double quotes but still getting the same error .            ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"123","16/02/25","19:02:40","My","hello","thankyou","welcome","visit again","hah' at line 1

Comment: Can you post the full command used to import?

Comment: sorry for late reply I tried to import the file through mysql software by giving file location. I surely want to import the csv file through code but for now i tried testing with software.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the fields in the csv file are not enclosed with double quotes. We need to enclosed the string (varchar) fields with double quotes and provide that information to MySQL import command as explained in [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/) example.